# Extjs or Deveexpress?

Tags: c#, curl, extjs

I want to develop mvc net application for finance and bank solution . i used Kendo UI in several application but Kendo UI have not stable.

I want to  know extjs is good solution or Devexpress  for use in  finance and bank solutions.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, recommended one product over another is outside of the remit of StackOverflow. You have to way the pros and cons of each against what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress is a good solution, I am also using it now as we speak - try the demo version and see if it also works for you.

http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Try.xml

Answer (score 2):

I would do a search on google.

Search for "bad service" "bugs" etc paired with Extjs and "Dev Express" respectively.

Take into account that one of them is probably more popular and will thus will give you more hits.

I am very pleased with the support from Dev Express, always got an answer to my queries within 24 hours.
I have no experience with Extjs